# Office365 Compliance: Is there a REST API to fetch all the DLP Policy and rules from Office365

Tags: office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I want to fetch all the defined DLP policies and Rules in my Office365 tenant. By Management Activity API I am able to get the DLP Event, That Event contains information Policy Id, Rule ID, SensitiveInformationID etc. Do we have REST API to fetch more detail about Policy , Rule and Sensitive information by providing Ids.

Does Office365 has API to fetch all the Policy and Rules for my tenant ?
Does Office365 has API to fetch policy detail, rule detail, SensitiveInformation detail by providing Ids?

Answer (score 0):

The Office 365 Reporting web service enables developers to integrate information on email and spam, antivirus activity, compliance status and Lync Online conferences and sessions into their custom service reporting applications and web portals. All the reports available in the admin portal, within the downloadable Microsoft Excel spreadsheets, and those accessed through Windows PowerShell cmdlets, are accessible using the Reporting web service. Users accessing the Reporting web service must have administrative rights in the organization.

Reporting service client sample in C#, Github source code is available too:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/dn864638.aspx

hope this helps.

Comment: Reporting web service has one end point "DlpDetectionsReport". This provides the DLP report. But that report doesn't contain the DLP policy Id. It has DLP policy name and Rule name. But my requirement is different, I have the Rule Id and Policy Id. Need to get Policy name and Rule name.

Comment: you need to develop that. if you have the policy id you can lookup the policy name. Same applies for the rule name. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The Kloudless unified APIs provide access to Exchange Online PowerShell via REST queries: https://blog.kloudless.com/2016/09/28/office-365-powershell-queries-via-rest-maximizing-the-kloudless-pass-through-api/

This is also available as an on-prem Docker container.

Disclosure: I work at Kloudless.